# Is it possible to take a screenshot of a circular selected area?

Tags: scripts, software-recommendation, programming, screenshot, productivity

When we take screenshots of selected areas on `Ubuntu` (using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Prt Scr</kbd>) we **always select a rectangular area**. So, I know I could just edit the image on some software like Inkscape to create a circle with the rectangular image, but I'd like to know if there's a configuration I can change for being able to **select different kinds of shapes (mainly circles) directly when I'm taking the screenshot.**

Is it possible?

Comment: that would be impossible surely, what size would the circle be and what would it's position be. Print Screen either prints the entire screen (rectangle) or the currently active window (rectangle)

Comment: Not really, when we use Shift+PrintScreen or Ctrl+Shift+PrintScreen we can print screen a rectangular selected area already... I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, I just want to change this rectangular shape that comes as default to a circular one.

Comment: The settings available via dconf Editor for org/gnome/gnome-screenshot are: auto-save-directory, border-effect, default-file-type, delay, include-border, include-icc-profile, include-pointer, last-save-directory, take-window-shot (depricated). Shape not present as a setting.

Comment: @Broadsworde ksnapshop can so why not ;) It has a "free hand" to make the most odd shapes; making a circle though... how good are you at making one Ramuyko ;)

Comment: @Ramuyko Another idea I had was to use the usual rectangular screenshot and just cut the biggest possible circle out of it, this way you could select the area as you’re used to. Are you interested in this approach as well?

Comment: @dessert Sure, that would be perfect because I'd be able to select a visible square on the screen

Comment: @Ramuyko No, you took me wrong – you would select with a rectangle as usual, e.g. with `gnome-screenshot`, and the script would then just crop out a circle (or even an ellipse if one wants).

Comment: @dessert  Yeah... That's exactly what I thought. It'd be cool because with gnome-screenshot I can visually see what I'm doing on the screen. So after taking the screenshot a script is watching the new images being taken and then it reformats the image based on the original image dimensions instead of the radius that I need to create pressing enter twice. Is that what you thought? I think that's useful too :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I put together a small script for circular screenshots, you need the following packages (though it’s adaptable for other screenshot programs and terminal emulators as well):

```bsh
sudo apt install xdotool gnome-screenshot imagemagick xterm
```

#### The script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

output=~/$(date +%F_%H%M%S).png
temp_screenshot=$(mktemp).png

read -p "Move cursor to center and press Enter"
eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
x_center=$X
y_center=$Y
read -p "Move cursor to edge and press Enter"
eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)

gnome-screenshot -f $temp_screenshot

radius=$(bc <<<"sqrt(($X-$x_center)^2+($Y-$y_center)^2)")

convert $temp_screenshot -alpha on \( +clone -channel a -evaluate multiply 0 -draw "ellipse $x_center,$y_center $radius,$radius 0,360" \) -compose DstIn -composite -trim "$output"
```

Save it as e.g. `~/circular_screenshot.bash` and make it executable with `chmod +x ~/circular_screenshot.bash`. When you run it, the script first asks you to move the mouse cursor to the center position and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then to move it to an edge position (doesn’t matter which, the script calculates the radius from the distance) and again press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The screen then flickers while the screenshot is taken (I recommend using `scrot $temp_screenshot` instead, it doesn’t show this odd behaviour.) and ImageMagick’s `convert`<sup>1</sup> is used to crop the image. The output is saved with a timestamp as the filename in your home directory, you can change this behaviour by editing the `output` variable of the script.

#### Example output

[image: example output]

#### Call without (or better: with an invisible) terminal window

I suppose you don’t want to have a terminal blocking your screen every time you make a screenshot like that, so here’s a solution for that; Call the script as follows (assuming the script was saved as `~/circular_screenshot.bash`):

```bsh
xterm -geometry 0x0-1-1 -e ~/circular_screenshot.bash
```

This runs the script in an invisible terminal window (icon with a red “X” and a blue “T”), you just need to make sure it’s focused when you type <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
You can assign this command to a keyboard shortcut using your desktop environment’s settings.

As ImageMagick is incredibly powerful you can adapt this script to output other shapes as well, I used `ellipse` with the same radius in both x and y direction to draw the circle above – change that to e.g. `$radius,$(bc <<<"$radius*0.5")` to get an ellipse with eccentricity above 0 instead.

<sup>1: I took the approach from [this thread on imagemagick.org](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=30488).</sup>

Comment: now xdotool combined with the freehand selection of ksnapshot would be something!

Comment: And you can add a custom shortcut in All settings > Keyboard, + add a custom shortcut, place this script in the command field and assign it to the Print key.

Comment: @SebastianStark What do you have in mind? A different selection (maybe similar to [my other idea](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035174/is-it-possible-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-circular-selected-area/1036139?noredirect=1#comment1686337_1035174))?

Comment: When I read xdotool I thought of a script that uses xdotool to move the mouse cursor in a circle to make use of the freehand selection of ksnapshot.

Comment: @SebastianStark Oh, now that’s a third way – please write a script and add an answer! ;)

Answer (score 6):

I've discovered some things here about screenshots. When we take screenshots on Ubuntu (mine is 16.04) we're actually using a software called `gnome-screenshot`. It's an open source software written in C and we can find its source code on GitHub in [this link](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-screenshot/tree/master/src):

[image]

Well, there's a file there called `screenshot-area-selection.c` that answers my question. It's a file with 361 lines of code so I'm not going to paste it here. But as far as I understood of this file (not much), it uses many functions that are structured around building a rectangular shape... Like in this piece of code:

```c
create_select_window (void)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GdkScreen *screen;
  GdkVisual *visual;

  screen = gdk_screen_get_default ();
  visual = gdk_screen_get_rgba_visual (screen);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_POPUP);
  if (gdk_screen_is_composited (screen) && visual)
    {
      gtk_widget_set_visual (window, visual);
      gtk_widget_set_app_paintable (window, TRUE);
    }

  g_signal_connect (window, "draw", G_CALLBACK (select_window_draw), NULL);

  gtk_window_move (GTK_WINDOW (window), -100, -100);
  gtk_window_resize (GTK_WINDOW (window), 10, 10);
  gtk_widget_show (window);

  return window;
}

typedef struct {
  GdkRectangle rectangle;
  SelectAreaCallback callback;
  gpointer callback_data;
  gboolean aborted;
} CallbackData;
```

So, my conclusion is that it's not possible to change any configuration to take screenshots using `gnome-screenshot` because its code is not structured for that... Although it's possible to download the code, change the code myself, recompile it and then use my own personalized version of `gnome-screenshot`.

Answer (score 4):

Using the same idea of the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036139/379686) I've created another script to take hexagonal screenshots and I'm sharing it here in case it's useful for someone else.

### **Example output**

[image: example of hexagonal screenshot]

### **The Script**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

output=~/$(date +%F_%H%M%S).png
temp_screenshot=$(mktemp).png

read -p "Move cursor to center and press Enter"
eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
x1=$X
y1=$Y
read -p "Move cursor to edge and press Enter"
eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
x2=$X
y2=$Y

gnome-screenshot -f $temp_screenshot

radius=$(bc -l <<<"sqrt(($x2-$x1)^2+($y2-$y1)^2)")
ca=$(bc -l <<<"$radius/sqrt(3)") 
h=$(bc -l <<<"$radius/(sqrt(3)/2)")

P1_x=$(bc <<<"$x1+$ca")
P1_y=$(bc <<<"$y1+$radius")

P2_x=$(bc <<<"$x1+$h")
P2_y=$(bc <<<"$y1")

P3_x=$(bc <<<"$x1+$ca")
P3_y=$(bc <<<"$y1-$radius")

P4_x=$(bc <<<"$x1-$ca")
P4_y=$(bc <<<"$y1-$radius")

P5_x=$(bc <<<"$x1-$h")
P5_y=$(bc <<<"$y1")

P6_x=$(bc <<<"$x1-$ca")
P6_y=$(bc <<<"$y1+$radius")

convert $temp_screenshot -alpha on \
        \( +clone -channel a -evaluate multiply 0 -draw \
        "polygon $P1_x,$P1_y $P2_x,$P2_y $P3_x,$P3_y $P4_x,$P4_y $P5_x,$P5_y $P6_x,$P6_y" \) \
        -compose DstIn -composite -trim "$output"
```

The process is exactly the same of the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036139/379686). In this case I just changed the script name:

"Save it as e.g. `~/hexagonal_screenshot.bash` and make it executable with `chmod +x ~/hexagonal_screenshot.bash`. When you run it, the script first asks you to move the mouse cursor to the center position and press Enter and then to move it to an edge position (doesn’t matter which, the script calculates the radius from the distance) and again press Enter. The screen then flickers while the screenshot is taken (I recommend using `scrot $temp_screenshot` instead, it doesn’t show this odd behavior.) and ImageMagick’s `convert` is used to crop the image. The output is saved with a timestamp as the filename in your home directory, you can change this behavior by editing the `output` variable of the script."

---

### **Additional Information**

In case someone is curious about the math involved, here is how I did it. For creating a **polygon with a different number of edges or different shapes** using `Imagemagick` the procedure would be the same: do the math and add or remove points to this part of the code `"polygon $P1_x,$P1_y $P2_x,$P2_y $P3_x,$P3_y $P4_x,$P4_y $P5_x,$P5_y $P6_x,$P6_y"`.

[image]